# Finding the point with the highest sum of values for three 2D arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So the question is to find the brightest spot in an image by summing three array values of the same height and width (red, green, blue). I believe I got everything right but my code sets the brightest (highest sum) point to the first one always. could anyone tell me what am I missing?

here is my code:

```java
public static int[] brightestSpot(int[][] red, int[][] green, int[][] blue) {
    int max = (red[0][0] + green[0][0] + blue[0][0]);
    int sum = 0;
    int[] point = new int[2]; // this is the array of the coordinates of match

    for (int i = 0; i > red.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < red[0].length; j++) {
            sum = (red[i][j] + green[i][j] + blue[i][j]);
            if (sum >= max) {
                max = sum;
                point[0] = i;
                point[1] = j;
            }
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    return point;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like outter loop `for(int i = 0; i > red.length; i++)` should be `for(int i = 0; i < red.length; i++)` to work as you intended.